# Calling url on base of incoming url

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to detect incoming url in asp.net page and making some decision on the base of that url But I am facing some problem here is my c# code the detect the url and also condtions

```
<script runat="server">

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (!IsPostBack)
       {
        String url = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];
        if (url != "http://172.17.0.221:84/CP.aspx")
        {
            Response.Redirect("http://a.sml.com.pk");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("http://172.17.0.221:85/MilkSale.aspx");
        }

       }        
    }    

</script>
```

But When I call the page from http://172.17.0.221:84/CP.aspx then it gives this error:

> This webpage has a redirect loop.
>
> The webpage at http://172.17.0.221:85/MilkSale.aspx has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Can any one tell me what may the error in this code?

Comment: It looks like it redirects many times to the same page. Log the urls of the pages being processed just to be sure. Try to call `Response.End` to end the processing.

Comment: Is this script also on the MilkSale.aspx page? If it is, it is going to fire *every* time. Change your else to else if url != "http://172.17.0.221:85/MilkSale.aspx" {} to check this.

Comment: seems like you causing a never ending page redirection..probably it always goes to **else** part. try using **else if** instead of **else**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your script statement is also on the MilkSale.aspx page, then it will fire every time the page is hit; in effect, it will redirect to itself forever (or, in this instance, until asp.net detects that it is requesting the same page over and over again).

To begin with:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
    String url = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
    {
        if (!url.ToUpper().Contains("CP.ASPX"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("http://a.sml.com.pk");
        }
        else if (!url.ToUpper().Contains("MILKSALE.ASPX") && !url.ToUpper().Contains("CP.ASPX"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("http://172.17.0.221:85/MilkSale.aspx");
        }
    }

   }        
}
```

Then this will fix the first issue. However, you then have to consider some other issues with your code;

1. You are doing case insensitive string matching.
2. You have IP addresses hard coded in your urls

1) is pretty easy to use; you can use `String.Compare(url, referrer, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` for example. In my code, I have used .ToUpper() but this is still fraught with issues (but makes for a compact example)

2) Is more difficult; you should really disassociate your redirect mechanism from the root url, or else you'll have to change your code everytime you change site. Either use the property `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery` or, preferably, look at [URL rewriting](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite).

Comment: Is url null by anychance? See edit. Also, try writing out the URL; your problem is that the else is ALWAYS firing :-)

Comment: Sir Situation is still same u can chek this here by clicking on hyperlink 202.125.144.34:84/CP.aspx

Comment: See update. You need to tell us what Http_Referrer contains :-)

Comment: But It is Not Redirecting to a.sml.com.pk when i call it from any other url except cp.aspx u can chek from my above link\

Comment: Ah, so it's no longer continuously redirecting?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9397/discussion-between-user1220667-and-dash)